# JavaFX, FXML Second scene is not opening

Tags: javafx, fxml, netbeans-8

I need help with this java code. I have three scene Login scene, Admin scene, and Player scene. When I run the program and enter that user and password the second should open. The problem now is that, the second scene is not opening. It's even connecting to the database, but that second scene is not opening. I have check the code, I can't see any problem with it. Can some please help me, what is happening.

Here is my main code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GiantsLogin extends Application {

private static Stage stage;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    setPrimaryStage(stage);
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GiantsLogin.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Giants Login");
    stage.show();
}

public static void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
    stage = primaryStage;
}

public static Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return stage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Here is the controller for my main:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GiantsLoginController {

public String dataName, serverName, password;
public int num;

private Connection connect = null;
private Statement stmt = null;

private boolean userPass, connected;

private Connections connection;


@FXML
private ComboBox<String> sType;
@FXML
public TextField dbName;
@FXML
private TextField sName;
@FXML
private Button loginB;
@FXML
private PasswordField sPassword;
@FXML
private Pane paneL;
@FXML
private GridPane gPane;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> uType;


ObservableList<String> sLists = FXCollections.observableArrayList("MySQL LOCAL", 
        "MYSQL REMOTE", "SQL SERVER LOCAL", "SQL SERVER");
ObservableList<String> uList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Player", 
        "Admin");



@FXML
public void initialize() {
    sType.setItems(sLists);
    uType.setItems(uList);
}

@FXML
public void loginBClick (Event event) {
    if (isAllFieldFillup()) {

        switch(uType.getValue().trim()) {
            case "Admin":
                if (connectCheck()) {
                    try {

                          admindStage(GiantsLogin.getPrimaryStage());

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            case "Player": 
                if (connectCheck()) {
                    try {
                        playerStage(GiantsLogin.getPrimaryStage());

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

public void admindStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("GiantsAdmin.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    stage.hide();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
    stage.show();
}

public void playerStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GiantsPlayer.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    stage.hide();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
    stage.show();
}

public void closeConnection () {

    if (connect != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            connect.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}

public boolean connectCheck() {
    connected = false;

    dataName = dbName.getText();
    serverName = sName.getText();
    password = sPassword.getText();


    switch (sType.getValue()) {
        case "MySQL LOCAL":
            num = 1;
            break;
        case "MYSQL REMOTE":
            num = 2;
            break;
        case "SQL SERVER LOCAL":
            num = 3;
            break;
        case "SQL SERVER":
            num = 4;
            break;
        default:

    }

    if (connect == null) {
        connect = Connections.getconnect(num, dataName, serverName, password);
    }

    if (connect == null ) {
        System.out.println("Still no connection");
    }

    if (stmt == null) {
        try {
            stmt = connect.createStatement();
            connected = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Alert notify = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            notify.setTitle("Blank filed");
            notify.setHeaderText(null);
            notify.setContentText("Incorrect login.");
            notify.showAndWait();

            connected = false;
        }


    }
    return connected;
}

private boolean isAllFieldFillup() {
    boolean allInfo;
    if (sType.getValue().equals("server type") && dbName.getText().isEmpty()
            && sName.getText().isEmpty() && sPassword.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert notify = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        notify.setTitle("Blank filed");
        notify.setHeaderText(null);
        notify.setContentText("You are missing some information.");
        notify.showAndWait();

        allInfo = false;
    }
    else {
        allInfo = true;
    }
    return allInfo;
}

}
```

> This is the where I set my stage for my Admin, and Player scene.
>
> ```
> public void admindStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
>     GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
>     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("GiantsAdmin.fxml"));
>     loader.setController(controller);
>     stage.hide();
>     stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
>     stage.show();
> }
>
> public void playerStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
>     GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
>     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GiantsPlayer.fxml"));
>     loader.setController(controller);
>     stage.hide();
>     stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
>     stage.show();
> }
> ```
>
> This is where I am call those two stage in the GiantsLoginController.
>
> ```
>  public void loginBClick (Event event) {
>     if (isAllFieldFillup()) {
>
>         switch(uType.getValue().trim()) {
>             case "Admin":
>                 if (connectCheck()) {
>                     try {
>
>                           admindStage(GiantsLogin.getPrimaryStage());
>
>                     }
>                     catch (Exception e) {
>
>                     }
>                 }
>             case "Player": 
>                 if (connectCheck()) {
>                     try {
>                         playerStage(GiantsLogin.getPrimaryStage());
>
>                     }
>                     catch (Exception e) {
>
>                     }
>                 }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This is the controller for my Admin scene

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GiantsAdminController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private Button connect = null;
private boolean connected;

private Statement stmt;

@FXML
private TextField aRank;
@FXML
private TextField aName;
@FXML
private TextField aPosition;
@FXML
private TextField aSchool;
@FXML
private TextField aAge;
@FXML
private TextField aWar;
@FXML
private Button clearB;
@FXML
private Button addB;
@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> rank;
@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> name;
@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> position;
@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> school;
@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> age;
@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> war;
@FXML
private TextField qSearch;
@FXML
private Button search;
@FXML
private Button singout;
@FXML
private Button delete;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> serverType;
@FXML
private TextField dbName;
@FXML
private TextField serverName;
@FXML
private TextField sPassword;

public GiantsAdminController(String message) {
    System.out.println("You said: " + message);
}

public GiantsAdminController() {
}

ObservableList<String> sLists = FXCollections.observableArrayList("MySQL LOCAL", 
        "MYSQL REMOTE", "SQL SERVER LOCAL", "SQL SERVER");
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    serverType.setItems(sLists);
}

@FXML
public void clearBClick (Event event) {
    aRank.clear();
    aName.clear();
    aPosition.clear();
    aSchool.clear();
    aAge.clear();
    aWar.clear();
}


@FXML
public void SingOutClick(Event event) throws IOException {


    Parent giantsLogin = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/giants/GiantsLogin.fxml"));

    Scene gLScene = new Scene(giantsLogin);
    gLScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(gLScene); 
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger. Without having your full code/setup available it's pretty hard to help you. You on the other hand could simply step through the code to identify the issue, which wouldn't take a minute. Using empty catch blocks is never a good idea, unless your code will continue to work properly, even in case a exception happens.Even then in most cases it's a good idea to log info somewhere.Especially in your case you're looking for the error an exception could provide valuable information.BTW:are you on purpose trying to use player and admin scene when `Admin` is selected?

Answer (score 0):

the following is just a proposition!.  with `admindStage()` method, do the following modification

```
 public void admindStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("GiantsAdmin.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    //stage.hide();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
    //stage.show();
}
```

Or using multiple stage:

```
public void admindStage() throws IOException {
    GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("GiantsAdmin.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
    stage.show();
}
```